# Problems with initializing form with VLOOKUP information

Tags: vba, excel

So I'm currently getting an "Expected end of statement" error upon running the provided code. I know that the problem lies in the way that Sub Searched function is written. I'm not really sure where to go from here but you should be able to get a feel for what I need to do from the code provided. Sub Searched works as a standalone just not with the initialize function.

Initialize

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
TextBox1.Text = Selection.Value
TextBox2.Text = Searched Sheets("CashHour1").Range("B2:E60"), Selection
End Sub
```

Command to autofill textbox in initialize function

```
Sub Searched(Rnge As Range, E_name As String)
On Error Resume Next
Sal = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(E_name, Rnge, 2, False)
Sal1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(E_name, Rnge, 3, False)

If Len(E_name) = 0 Then
MsgBox "Select an employee"

ElseIf Len(Sal) < 1 Then
Hours = "OFF"

Else
Hours = Sal & " - " & Sal1
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Change `Searched` to a Function, and then do `TextBox2.Text = Searched(Sheets("CashHour1").Range("B2:E60"), Selection.Value)

Comment: @DavidZemens Made the changes. I'm not getting an error anymore but it's not filling any information into TextBox2.

Comment: because your function isn't returning anything.  See my answer below I think it will be better than using a `Function` for this, just modify the sub to accept the `TextBox` directly and manipulate it inside the `Searched` subroutine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Searched` is a Subroutine, not a function, so it can't return a value.

There are two ways you could handle this, one would be to change `Searched` to a function, but I would probably just modify the `Searched` subroutine to also accept a TextBox argument.

```
Searched Sheets("CashHour1").Range("B2:E60"), Selection.Value, TextBox2
```

So modify the sub to accept a textbox argument:

```
Searched(Rnge As Range, E_name As String, tb as MSForms.TextBox)
On Error Resume Next
Sal = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(E_name, Rnge, 2, False)
Sal1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(E_name, Rnge, 3, False)

If Len(E_name) = 0 Then
MsgBox "Select an employee"

ElseIf Len(Sal) < 1 Then
Hours = "OFF"

Else
Hours = Sal & " - " & Sal1
End If

'## Write to the textbox:
tb.Text = Hours
End Sub
```

**NOTE** You have a lot of undeclared variables and your error-handling is non-existent, so this might still raise some problems, for example if `Len(E_Name) = 0` then the TextBox1.Text will be `0`...

See also this answer, about why you should **NOT** use `Selection` in your code:

[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select/10717999#10717999)

Comment: I plan to expand the code to handle specific errors that can arise but I just needed to get that working before I expand on the code any more. Thanks for the selection tip but for this particular case I'm not sure I'll be able to avoid it. The user is essentially selecting a name from a list of about 60 names and then running this code to return the relevant data.

Comment: You can always avoid it, and it is always a good idea to do so.

Comment: Avoid it with an Inputbox, or if absolutely necessary to use `Selection` as a way of capturing user input, you should assign the `Selection.Value` (or `Selection.Address`, etc.) to an appropriately typed variable.